# Pandas: Convert multiple dataframes in a dictionary to an excel workbook with each key as each tab's name

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I created multiple dataframes using a for loop and stored it in a dictionary `d` using the code below:

```
def cleanTab(v):
    df = pd.read_excel('file:///H:\somepath\MuniLevelData_All_Inflow.xlsx', sheet_name = v)
    df = df[(df.Municipalities.str.contains('Lehigh, PA')) | (df.Municipalities.str.contains('Northampton, PA'))]
    return df
d ={}
for name in l1:
    d[name] = cleanTab(name)
```

Now I have all the dataframes (124) in `d`. Is there a way for me to put all these dataframes in a multi-tab workbook with each key as each tab's name?

Comment: yes, according to pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). See example near the end.

Comment: you can use pd.ExcelWriter and use a for loop to loop through your dict, I've done a 60 tab excel workbook before but not more than that 120 + is massive

Comment: @Datanovice let me try that when I get a chance. It will be broken into two counties so two excel sheets with 60+ tabs will work.

Comment: are the names for the tabs in your dataframe? let me know and I can adapt an answer accordingly.

Comment: @Datanovice Sorry for the late response. Got caught up in things today. No the dataframes don't contain the names. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data